# foreach outputs all the array items at once for each iteration

Tags: php

`Foreach` outputs all items in array in each iteration but I want to be able to output one item per iteration. I'm trying to loop through array of images and create Bootstrap carousel. Inside `foreach` it creates one div wrapper per iteration but all the rest of inside child elements gets repeated multiple times for some reason.

My array looks like this: `Array ( [0] => 11471 [1] => 11473 [2] => 11472 [3] => 11474 )`

And this is the code:

```
                <?php if (get_post_type(get_the_ID()) === "ebooks" && get_field('images_for_slider')) :
                    $images = get_field('images_for_slider');
                    $imagesArr = explode(',', $images);
                    $counter = 0;
                    if ($images) {
                ?>
                        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <?php $active = true;
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($imagesArr as $image) :
                                ?>
                                    <div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($active == true) ? "active" : "" ?>">
                                        <?php if ($counter === 0) : ?>
                                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image);
                                                                            ?>"></img>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                    </div>

                                    <?php $active = false;
                                    $counter++;
                                    ?>
                                <?php endforeach;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
                    }
                endif;
```

The output in HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
                                                                                                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="test">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"></div>

                                                                                                        <div class="carousel-item ">
                                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="test">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"></div>

                                                                                                        <div class="carousel-item ">
                                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="test">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"></div>

                                                                                                        <div class="carousel-item ">
                                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="test">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"><img class="d-block w-100" src="test"></div>

                                                                                                </div>
```

As you can see I get 4 `<div class="carousel-item ">` items which is great but all the image tags inside each of those parent elements are created 4 times whereas I want to show one image per parent element `<div class="carousel-item ">`. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't look like that code could produce that output. You may not be running the code you think you are.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code that would explain what is happening, however, you have do have `<img ....></img>` and that is incorrect as the `<img...>` tag should not have a closing `</img>`.  Lose the `</img` as this may be confusing the html rendering.

Comment: @gview I don't know how to even explain this but if I wrap my code in 
`foreach ($images as $image) {
                                echo '<div class="carousel-items"> ' .  wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'my_slider') . '</div>';
                            }` it works fine with one `img` tag being rendered inside `div`. But if I change the class name to `carousels-item` which is a bootstrap class, I get duplicated img tags inside of that div. Why would it do that?

Comment: Is this a new problem?  The class should be `carousel-item` not `carousels-item`

Comment: I mispeled when typing a comment. This looks to be some kind of bootstrap bug but I can’t find anything online.

Comment: Take a look at the console using the chrome debug tools, and perhaps debug whatever javascript is running.